# Changing Position of Keys in Associative Arrays

Tags: arrays, sorting, associative-array, key

I'm creating a form generator that takes some configuration arrays and build the html. Ex: I have the following associative array to describe how the fields should be displayed:

```
$fieldSpec = array(
    'nome' => array(
        'label' => 'Nome',
    ),
    'descricao' => array(
        'label' => 'Descrição',
    ),
    'preco' => array(
        'label' => 'Preço',
    ),
);
```

problem: I want to reposition the keys easily without having to be cutting & pasting all the time. So i thought to ask somebody if they know a function or class to manage this; it would have to be something like this:

```
ChangeKeyPosition(&$fieldSpec,'preco','up',2);

// that would produce:
$fieldSpec = array(
    'preco' => array( # <- notice this element came 2 levels up
            'label' => 'Preço',
        ),
    'nome' => array(
        'label' => 'Nome',
    ),
    'descricao' => array(
        'label' => 'Descrição',
    ),

);
```

other possible features I would like to have:

```
ChangeKeyPosition(&$fieldSpec,'descricao','down',1);
// send element "preco" to the top
ChangeKeyPosition(&$fieldSpec,'preco','top');
// send element "nome" to the end of the array
ChangeKeyPosition(&$fieldSpec,'nome','bottom');
// place "nome" before "preco"
ChangeKeyPosition(&$fieldSpec,'nome','before','preco');
// place "nome" after "descricao"
ChangeKeyPosition(&$fieldSpec,'nome','after','descricao');
// place "preco" between "nome" and "descricao"
ChangeKeyPosition(&$fieldSpec,'preco','between',array('nome','descricao'));
```

I would even prefer to work with an object wrapping the array reference like this:

```
$man = new KeyPositionManager(&$fieldSpec);
$man->up('preco',2);
$man->after('nome','descricao');
etc...
```

**Update:**
So I ended up creating a set of functions myself to do just what I was asking for. It may or may not be useful for somebody else:

```
function array_key_move(&$oarr, $key, $move)
{
    $keys = array_keys($oarr);
    $opos = array_search($key,$keys);
    if($opos===false) return;
    $npos = $opos + $move + ($move > 0 ? +0.1 : -0.1);
    $keys["$npos"] = $key;
    unset($keys[$opos]);
    ksort($keys);
    foreach($keys as $k)
    {
        $narr[$k] = $oarr[$k];
    }
    $oarr = $narr;
}

function array_key_set_at(&$oarr, $tkey, $nkey, $nval, $before = true)
{
    $tpos = array_search($tkey,array_keys($oarr));
    if($tpos===false) return;
    $narr = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($oarr as $k => $v)
    {
        if($tpos==$i)
        {
            $before AND $narr[$nkey] = $nval;
            $narr[$k] = $v;
            $before OR $narr[$nkey] = $nval;
        } else $narr[$k] = $v;
        $i++;
    }
    $oarr = $narr;
}

function array_key_move_before(&$oarr, $key_element, $key_target)
{
    $copy_element = $oarr[$key_element];
    unset($oarr[$key_element]);
    array_key_set_at($oarr, $key_target, $key_element, $copy_element, TRUE);
}

function array_key_move_after(&$oarr, $key_element, $key_target)
{
    $copy_element = $oarr[$key_element];
    unset($oarr[$key_element]);
    array_key_set_at($oarr, $key_target, $key_element, $copy_element, FALSE);
}

function array_key_move_start(&$oarr, $key)
{
    if(!isset($oarr[$key])) return;
    $narr[$key] = $oarr[$key];
    foreach($oarr as $k => $v)
    {
        $k!=$key AND $narr[$k]=$v;
    }
    $oarr = $narr;
}

function array_key_move_end(&$oarr, $key)
{
    if(!isset($oarr[$key])) return;
    foreach($oarr as $k => $v)
    {
        $k!=$key AND $narr[$k]=$v;
    }
    $narr[$key] = $oarr[$key];
    $oarr = $narr;
}

function array_key_set_start(&$oarr,$key,$val)
{
    $oarr[$key] = $val;
    array_key_move_start($oarr,$key);
}


function array_key_set_end(&$oarr,$key,$val)
{
    $oarr[$key]=$val; # :-)
}

function array_key_switch2(&$oarr,$ka,$kb)
{
    $keys = array_keys($oarr);
    if(($kapos = array_search($ka, $keys))===false) return;
    if(($kbpos = array_search($kb, $keys))===false) return;
    $i = 0;
    foreach($oarr as $k => $v)
    {
        if($i==$kapos)
            $narr[$kb] = $oarr[$ka];
        elseif($i==$kbpos)
            $narr[$ka] = $oarr[$kb];
        else
            $narr[$k] = $v;
        $i++;
    }
    $oarr = $narr;
}
```

**Examples:**

**array_key_move($arr,'f',-3);**

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [b] => 2
    [f] => 6 # <- "f"
    [c] => 3 #
    [d] => 4 #
    [e] => 5
)
```

**array_key_move($arr,'a',+1);**

```
Array
(
    [b] => 2 #
    [a] => 1 # <- "a"
    [f] => 6
    [c] => 3
    [d] => 4
    [e] => 5
)
```

**array_key_move_after($arr,'b','e');**

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [f] => 6
    [c] => 3
    [d] => 4
    [e] => 5
    [b] => 2 # <- "b" after "e"
)
```

**array_key_move_start($arr,'b');**

```
Array
(
    [b] => 2 # <- "b" at start
    [a] => 1
    [f] => 6
    [c] => 3
    [d] => 4
    [e] => 5
)
```

**array_key_set_start($arr,'r',7);**

```
Array
(
    [r] => 7 # <- prepended
    [b] => 2
    [a] => 1
    [f] => 6
    [c] => 3
    [d] => 4
    [e] => 5
)
```

*obs: the above is not an alias to array_unshift
ex: array_unshift($arr,array('r'=>7));
would produce:*

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [r] => 7
        )

    [b] => 2
    [a] => 1
    [f] => 6
    [c] => 3
    [d] => 4
    [e] => 5
)
```

and finally

**array_key_switch2($arr,'r','e');**

```
Array
(
    [e] => 7 # <-
    [b] => 2
    [a] => 1
    [f] => 6
    [c] => 3
    [d] => 4
    [r] => 5 # <-
)
```

Comment: Just a side note: if you're relying on the order of keys in an assoc array as part of your design, you're doing something wrong. Regardless, take a look at the ksort() function. It's not what you're asking for, but it'll make things consistent for you.

Comment: I thought of having a separate array telling the order i want for displaying the elements, like $order = array('preco','descricao',etc...). if a $order argument is not given then the generator would chose the default order. Would this be a better design choice?

Comment: In PHP order of keys is preserved isn't it, i.e. the order of keys is the order in which they were added to the array, unless the keys are manipulated in some way (e.g. ksort)? That being said, if you want to start messing with key order, rather maintain a second array with strict numeric indices as you describe above. It's certainly easier to move values around in an array rather than keys.

Comment: Besides, you can't really move the order of keys in an assoc array, can you? You'd have to construct a new array and insert the items one by one in a new order. I may be wrong tho...

Comment: Yup, that's the only way I can think of doing it.

Comment: @fabio: If your writing your form generator for actual practical use, you might want to take a look at the following: http://php-form-generator.com/ http://www.formfields.com/ http://phpforms.net/ and then there's my own creation https://sourceforge.net/projects/backtofront/ Which I started writing because none of the aforementioned things did exactly what I needed

Comment: @Lior: I think you are right, we would have to create a new array. And I think I know now why it wouldn't be a good design solution because one thing is for configuration and the order of display is something related to presentation. However, i would still like to have a manager like the one i described in the case where I have too many keys in the assoc array; in this case i could want to switch position among/between just a couple of elements and not have to do everything manually.

Comment: @fabio: Best way to do it would be to wrap a pair of arrays, one containing the actual data, the other containing the key order, in a class, and provide methods for manipulating key order and also proving the iterator interface (and possibly others) for convenience.

Comment: @sirlark: thanks for the reference. i have to write something for my own and present it, explain how I did it, etc., so it is not just for practical use. Also, some third-party form-generators i have seen so far are very complicated and difficult to learn.

Comment: +1 @sirlark's suggestion. Take a look at SPL for iterators. You could create a class that'll behave exactly like what you've described and still be accessible using the array notation.

Comment: ok, thanks for your time guys, i'll see what i can do to help myself.

Comment: I ended up creating the functions I needed (see the update). Maybe i'm the only one who will ever make use of them ;P